# Magento 2.1: Do we need to do anything special for the controll action to accept HTTP Post with Json Payload?

Tags: magento2, module, magento-2.1, controllers

I have a controller action that will be used for webhook handler.

When I did the form post to that URL with header content-type:

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded

My load is:

> MyVariableOne=ValueOne&MyVariableTwo=ValueTwo

On the action's execute function, I had $data as

> $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

When I do var_dump, I got:

> array(2) {
>    ["MyVariableOne"]=>
>    string(8) "ValueOne"
>    ["MyVariableTwo"]=>
>    string(8) "ValueTwo"
>   }

But when I change the content-type to application/json and set payload to:

> {"MyVariableOne":"ValueOne","MyVariableOne":"ValueTwo"}

the var_dump now become:

> array(0) {
>   }

Am I missing some steps to make my webhook hanlder support

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Turned out JSON Payload doesn't like to be mapped by $this->getRequest()->getPostValue(); Instead I have to fall back to primitive PHP command.

> $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
>
> $data = json::decode($request_body,true);